# One login for hotel guests flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication

I’m developing an app for a hotel. No booking function. An app with touristic information about the country and the hotel. It’s an extra service for guests that stay in the hotel. All the info in one app. However I want only the guests to be able to use the app.

So I was thinking how I could fix that.. maybe a login with roomnumber and a fixed password that changes monthly?

I do not want the guests to put effort in registering. It needs to be be as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the app access a network over wifi with local-only addresses (10.x, for example) for authorization.  If you're not there, it obviously won't work.

Comment: The app has tourist information, like things to see, opening hours, entrance fees etc. So the app should be accessible outside the hotel as well.

Comment: Then save an authorization when the hotel wifi is noticed, and check that when away from the hotel.